# How do I override the Umbraco built-in media library methods to use s3?

Tags: umbraco, media-library, umbraco6

I'm currently looking to move my Umbraco installation over to a load balanced setup.  In order to do this, I need to move the Media library over to a CDN like Amazon's S3.  I tested a few plugins that allow upload to s3, but they all list media files on the local file directory.  This flat out will not work.

I was thinking I would write the code to browse the CDN, but how can I override the built-in media library code so that it uses my version instead?  I didn't see a clear way to do this in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

I am using this plugin: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/amazon-s3-media for amazon s3. The source code is here: https://bitbucket.org/gibedigital/umbraco-amazons3provider . He recently just updated the plugin. The plugin does not use the local file system. The developer was pretty responsive (and made a few updates for me when I asked).

However, I am adding to his project because his plugin did not allow saving within a predefined directory (amazon's virtual directories). But his source code is a start.

Good luck,

Robin

Comment: The link to the plugin is dead. I found a similar plugin https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ast-amazon-s3/